# How to prevent div.click event when another element clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to prevent click event but `e.stopPropagation()` doesn't work.

I'm trying to write something like Jtable . I use div as pagination buttons(1) and another element is delete button.

I need to disable pagination buttons when delete confirmation box is popping up . After click del or cancel  "I want my pagination buttons work again".
Is there any solution? 
[image]

```
function deleteit() {
  $(".del").click(function() {
    $(".divbutton").click(function(e) {
    alert(1);   
    e.stopPropagation(); 
  });
}

$(".deletebtn").click(function() {
  deleteit();
});

$(".divbutton").click(function() { // I want to prevent this from click
  //ajax send and display data
});
```

I know that I should use input  disabled instead of div, but I need to use div.
edit:add image to make it understandable.

Comment: Which part is related to "div.click" and wich part to "other elements"

Comment: Please fix your indentation. And your syntax isn't valid. Makes it hard to tell what you're trying to do.

Comment: ah sorry another element is .deletebtn   and i use div as button .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of preventing the click handler... remove the registered handler using [.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/), here [namespaced event name](http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-names) is used because we want to remove only a very specific handler

```
function deleteit() {
    $(".del").click(function () {
        $(".divbutton").off('click.delete')
    })
}

$(".deletebtn").click(function () {
    deleteit();
});

$(".divbutton").on('click.delete', function () { // I want to prevent this from click
    //ajax send and display data
});
```

Why your code is not working? because stopping propagation will prevent the bubbling up of the event but in your case both the event are registered to the `divbutton` so both of them will get triggered even if propagation is prevented.

Another way is to use [stopImmediatePropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/) even that is not possible here because your delete registers the handler later and it will get executed only after the first one is called